# I can't run even simple code of python in my PyCharm IDE. Do need support

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, pycharm

[Screenshot of which when i tried to create a new project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v9lMM.jpg)[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lieZ0.jpg)I can't run my python files with pycharm. It says "Error running 'main': Cannot run program "C:\Users\pbrah\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python3.10.exe" (in directory "C:\Users\pbrah\PycharmProjects\pythonProject9"): CreateProcess error=1920, The file cannot be accessed by the system"

[The Screen shot of the mentioned issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJuG7.jpg)

when i had to install Django there was an issues with Django working inpycharm.so I uninstalled and  reinstalled PyCharm. Django stated working but now simple python codes doesn't works at all and the above mentioned problem was coming forward.

[screen shot when I try adding new project]

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should make sure that Python is properly installed in you system.

In CommandPrompt or PowerShell:

```
python -V
```

will print your python version, and if the command is working, means that your system can find Python.

Then, get into PyCharm:

1. Open Settings:  File > Settings (or just ctrl + alt + s)
2. Set the project interpreter: On the settings left tab open "Project:NameOfYourProject"
3. Point the interpreter to your Python .exe

That being said. I would like to complement that one best practices in development with Python is to have your packages independent from your system. installed in a [virtual environment](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html).

So instead of pointing to Python interpreter in your system, you set it to the virtual environment, for example:

```
C:\path\to\your\project\venv\Scripts\python.exe
```

EDIT:

Assuming you already have python properly installed in your system, to set up a project, for the first time.

```
# navigate to your desired folder. I will say just 'C:\Projects'
# set up your project folder
cd C:\Projects
mkdir MyProject
cd MyProject

# upgrade pip and install virtual env
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
pip install virtualenv

# create virtual env
python -m venv venv
```

Then, inside PyCharm you would set the interpreter to:

```
D:\Projects\MyProject\venv\Scripts\python.exe
```